# Changing the math font in pdflatex

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

After not-so-little effort, I managed to use a `.otf` I downloaded with the `pdflatex` engine. Once the `.fd` file is created, a simple `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{<MyFontFamilyName>}` lets me use said font in the text.

However changing the value of `\rmdefault` has no effect in math mode. If I was using `XeLaTeX`, I'd use `\setmathfont`, but since I'm not doing that how can I get the font to work in math mode (including the letters of the greek alphabet)?

Comment: you haven't said what 8bit font you made, in classic pdflatex encoding setup you would need a T1 encoded font for text, an OT1 font for fam0 (\mathrm and uppercase Greek) and OML encoded one for math italic, including lower case Greek, and possibly other encodings depending how many of the characters in the original font you need.(None of the standard pdflatex math fonts use more than 128 characters per font)

Comment: If you just want to use your existing text font in math without setting up a new math font font set that's easier, does the font already include Greek? what encoding is it in?

Comment: The font encoding is T1, and it does already include Greek letters. What's the difference between the output of `\mathrm` and regular text, and between math italic and regular italic (i.e. the one I get with `\textit`)?

Comment: T1 encoding does not include Greek.

Comment: T1 is the encoding I chose when creating the tex font metrics with `otftotfm`. I think that the `.otf` includes greek because when I compile with XeLaTeX greek letters are available. To get them I could just run `otftotfm` again choosing a different encoding, but once I do that, how do I include it in my document?

Comment: look at eg latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty for how to declare the math fonts once you have the fd files I guess you want at least a T1 encoded file for text an then OT1  for math operators and \mathrm  and uppercase Greek and OML for math italic and lower case greek.

Comment: Maybe I should make a new post to ask this, but do you know what's the name of the file for the `OML` encoding? Like for `T1` the file is `ec.enc`, for `OT1` I used `fontools_ot1.enc`, and for `OML`?

Comment: texmital.enc from same directory as ec.enc i guess

Answer (score 2):

With `mathastext` the text font will be used for math. Make sure to place this package after the redefinition if the default font. If desired the `italic` option can be activated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

\usepackage[
%   italic,
    symbolgreek
    ]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

text

\[
text \alpha
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]